# Split text area into an array based on keyCode and add li tags to each line - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, textarea

I am new to JavaScript so struggling to get this over the line. I have a form with a textarea field. After each keypress event of the enter key I need each line to get wrapped in li tags. Then once submitted the data is outputted as a list. I am using Javascript not JQuery. The problem is when I add the li tags the opening tag is always added to the first item and ends up having multiple opening li tags and the closing tags work as they should.

I have tried this so far.
HTML

```
<textarea id="form__comments" name="comments" class="form__comments" rows="10" onkeypress="addLiTag(event);"></textarea>
```

JS

```
function addLiTag(e) {
  const commentValue = document.getElementById("form__comments").value
  var lines = commentValue.split(/\r?\n/)
  var key = e.keyCode

  // If the user has pressed enter
  if (key === 13) {

    document.getElementById("form__comments").value = "<li>" + lines + "</li>"

    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

This is the output within the Textarea

`<li><li><li>One</li>,two</li>Three,</li>`

Comment: [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea?qs=%3Ctextarea%3E#technical_summary) can contain plain text only. If you can see an actual list, you're working with some other element.

Comment: Sorry @Teemu this was my first question on Stackoverflow and didn't use the correct method to display the textarea content. I have amended and now shows the HTML.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought, but I had to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main issue with your existing code is that when you add the value back to your `textarea`, you wrap an array (the `lines` variable) inside of an opening and closing `<li>` tag, rather than wrapping each line inside of its own tag.

Also when adding the value back, I'm assuming you want to preserve the lines as well (meaning each `<li>` is also on its own line), in which case you also would need to add back the newline character after each line.

And lastly, to prevent duplicate `<li>` tags being added, the simplest thing is to just remove the tags and parse the value of your text area again (this also can prevent issues with editing previous lines).

```js
const addLiTag = e => {
  let lines = document.querySelector("#form__comments").value.replaceAll("<li>", "").replaceAll("</li>", "").split(/\r?\n/)

  if(e.keyCode === 13) document.querySelector("#form__comments").value = "<li>" + lines.join("</li>\n<li>") + "</li>"
}

document.querySelector("#form__comments").addEventListener("keypress", addLiTag)
```

```html
<textarea id="form__comments" name="comments" class="form__comments" rows="10"></textarea>
```

#### Notes

I'm sure this could also be done with a single Regular Expression that splits on either a newline or the `</li>\n<li>` delimeter, rather than using two `.replaceAll()` calls, however I'm not that great at Regular Expressions. But hopefully this answer demonstrates the concept of removing all of the `<li>` tags and re-parsing the value each time.

Comment: this is brilliant. Thank you for your quick response and for the explanation. I really appreciate the help. Thanks again.